# Sharing of Power BI work to external users

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I created a dashboard in Power BI and would like to share the work with my friends through my novypro profile. But in novypro, it asked me for the embedded url. As I am currently using my school mail id for all my Power BI works, I couldn't see the publish to web option in order to get the embedded URL.

In the other links I tried, I learned that I have to check with the tenant option under Admin Portal. But under Admin Portal I couldn't see anything like that and I have attached the image below.

[image]

Is there any other way to send our report to the external users?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't see any other tenant settings in the Admin portal is that you are not an Admin.  You need to ask an admin to allow you to publish to the web.

> The Power BI admin portal has settings that control who can publish to
> the web. Work with your organization's Power BI administrator to
> change the Publish to web tenant settings in the admin portal.
>
> For smaller organizations or individuals who signed up for Power BI,
> you may not have a Power BI administrator yet. Follow our process for
> admin takeover. Once you have a Power BI administrator, they can
> enable creating embed codes for you.
>
> Established organizations usually already have a Power BI
> administrator. People in any of the following roles can act as a Power
> BI administrator:
>
> Global administrators Users with the Power BI service admin role in
> Azure Active Directory You need to find one of these people in your
> organization and ask them to update the Publish to web tenant settings
> in the admin portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web#find-your-power-bi-administrator

Alternatively you can sign up for your own [Developer Tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/profile), which includes E5 so you can use Power BI there and have full control.